# import select ImportError: No module named select

Tags: ros, rosdep, ros-hydro, beginner-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since yesterday I've been having a problem to use the next command:

> $ rospack depends1 rospy

And any other command like this.

I receive the next output:

> $ rospack depends1 rospy
>
> failed to load symbols, rosdep will
> not function properly Cannot import
> rospkg, rosdep will not function
> properly Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py",
> line 37, in 
> import subprocess   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 429, in 
> import select ImportError: No module named select Error in
> sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py",
> line 61, in apport_excepthook
> from io import StringIO   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51,
> in 
> import _io ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so:
> undefined symbol:
> PyUnicodeUCS4_EncodeUTF32
>
> Original exception was: Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py",
> line 37, in 
> import subprocess   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 429, in 
> import select ImportError: No module named select Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py",
> line 37, in 
> import subprocess   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 429, in 
> import select ImportError: No module named select Error in
> sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py",
> line 61, in apport_excepthook
> from io import StringIO   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51,
> in 
> import _io ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so:
> undefined symbol:
> PyUnicodeUCS4_EncodeUTF32
>
> Original exception was: Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rospack.py",
> line 37, in 
> import subprocess   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py",
> line 429, in 
> import select ImportError: No module named select [rospack] Error:
> could not find python module
> 'rosdep2.rospack'. is rosdep
> up-to-date (at least 0.10.4)?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal), with ROS-HYDRO.

My rosdep version is:

> $ rosdep --version

> 0.10.25

I've already tried to find some solution, but I couldn't. I've tried to 'autoremove' ros and clean install again, but nothing changed.

When I try to 'import select' using the python environment in terminal, everything is OK.

My PYTHONPATH is OK, as follows:

> $ echo $PYTHONPATH

> /home/usr/catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/hydro/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Can anybody help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/148981/import-select-importerror:-no-module-named-select/) by [mah_mpc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14386/mah_mpc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mah_mpc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14386/mah_mpc/) on 2014-04-06**:
Thanks for trying to help! I had some other problems with my ubuntu and so I re-installed everything! Now I don't have that problem anymore, neither the other problems... =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I discovered why I had that problem! Like tfoote thought, I have some custom paths, and the python paths got into a conflict! I just organized them and everything is in ok now!

---

Originally posted by [mah_mpc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14386/mah_mpc/) with karma: 16 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [asiron](https://answers.ros.org/users/18762/asiron/) on 2014-06-02**:
Could you please tell me what was your problem, I have been having the same problem for 2 weeks, and I  have yet to solve it, my env variables seem ok to me

**Comment by [mah_mpc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14386/mah_mpc/) on 2014-06-02**:
As I'm working with NAO robot, I indicate its paths in the .bashrc file, one of them indicates the $PYTHONPATH. This path got into a conflit with the paths in ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash. Everything was solved when I put the source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash AFTER exporting the NAO's python path.

**Comment by [mah_mpc](https://answers.ros.org/users/14386/mah_mpc/) on 2014-06-02**:
Hope it helps! =)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you say how to reproduce your environment? It looks like you have several custom paths. Or can you reproduce this with a minimal environment to isolate the problem?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-04-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1